# passing parameters to a stored Proc accepting in parameter of type XML type from vb.net

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, oracle

I have a storedproc accepts parameters in XMLtype as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetDetails(
                            p_para  IN  XMLTYPE,
```

i have to pass 4 parameters to this proc how to do this?

i am passing param as db.Parameters("p1", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, _
            '              LN.Length, CObj(LN), Data.ParameterDirection.Input)

and tried this db.Parameters("p1", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.XMLType, _
            '              LN.Length, CObj(LN), Data.ParameterDirection.Input)

Comment: any sample with full source code about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a XMLDoc object and add nodes to it ..the nodes name should be same as parameters name in the procedure and
db.parameters("p1", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.xmltype,xmldoc.outerxml.length, cobj(xmldoc.outerxml),Data.ParameterDirection.Input)